# detect a line in an image and calculate his length

Tags: opencv, detection, lines

i have an image and i want to detect lines on it and calculate their length with OpenCv  and C++.
with a binary image, i can find all the non zero pixels, but i have problems to find the start point and the end point of each line in order to calculate the length.

```
for (int i = 0; i < edge_img->height; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < edge_img->width; j++){

        if (edge_img->imageData[i*edge_img->widthStep + j] = 255 ){
            p1.x = j;
            p1.y = i;
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone give me the logic to use in order to find lines.

Thank you

Comment: Try HoughLinesP function

Comment: Yes i know Hough transform functions but i'm looking for some examples of image segmentation and edge linking technics. i can for example use a 3*3 segmentation and test the similarity of pixel, then link them. I think i can find the first and the last point that way.  If you have any example related to that , please give me the link... Thx

Comment: not sure how this can be done, but your provided code has an error, I guess it should be: `if (edge_img->imageData[i*edge_img->widthStep + j] == 255 )` if you didnt want to make an assignment ;)

Comment: As always, an example image would be useful. Also, you should be using Mat instead of defunct IplImage. Are the lines only 1 pixel wide?

Comment: unfortunatly, i don't have enough reputation to post my image, but it just a simple image with 3 lines inside and others objects. i just want the length of each line (then  the first and the last point for each line). Thank you

Comment: Use findContours to segment the lines. Then for each contour choose the two points with either maximum distance or minimum neighbors.